# exports or export?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Should I use 'export' because coffee is uncountable?

> Coffee is the top **export** from this country.

Should apples be viewed as one category of exports and so the singular **export** should be used, or should they be viewed as individual apples and so the plural **exports** should be used?

> Apples are the top **exports/export?** from this country.

I wrote the two sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export is one category of some thing exported.

Apples are a top export of [country]. [countable]
Coffee is another export of [country]. [uncountable]

You wouldn't say: Apple or an apple is an export of [country].